# Using an action to scroll CollectionView to the next cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uislider

I have a horizontal collectionview that adds a new cell every time I tap the button. I am attempting to scroll the collectionview to the next cell once the cells are no longer visible each time I tap the button.

The code I have now is not working properly

Code:

```
@IBAction func random(_ sender: Any) {

    resultsCollection.reloadData()

    let collectionBounds = resultsCollection.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(resultsCollection.contentOffset.x - collectionBounds.size.width))
    self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)

}

func moveToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {

    let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x : contentOffset ,y : resultsCollection.contentOffset.y ,width : resultsCollection.frame.width,height : resultsCollection.frame.height)
        resultsCollection.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

How can I fix this so that it scrolls correctly when I tap the button?

Comment: Did you try this ? `self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: yourIndex, section: yourSection), at: .left, animated: false)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reload your data, call this lines.

```
let lastItem = resultsCollection(resultsCollection, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 1
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: lastItem, section: 0)

resultsCollection.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to achieve your needs. For animation, you just need to pass value true/false in animated of `scrollToRow` function.
Hope this will help you!

**To scroll top without animation**

```
func scrollToTopWithoutAnimation() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if self.dataArray.count > 0 {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
         }
     }
}
```

**To scroll top with animation**

```
func scrollToTopWithAnimation() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if self.dataArray.count > 0 {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

         }
     }
}
```

> **Set IndexPath row as per your needs**